# How to activate scheduled deletion for Dataproc cluster using Python API?

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataproc

For manual creation of **scheduled deletion** for Dataproc cluster I can use the next parameter `--max-idle=30m`.

But how to activate **scheduled deletion** using Python API? Any hints where should I check?

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at code, it seems that it's available in `v1beta2` Dataproc API [Python client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/blob/e3335341bd47885add32796428adf288f9bb0623/dataproc/google/cloud/dataproc_v1beta2/proto/clusters.proto#L388).

[Here is an example](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/45d24e79eab98589b1b0509e920811cbf778048b/airflow/contrib/operators/dataproc_operator.py#L377) of how to set it (from [Airflow DataprocClusterCreateOperator](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/integration.html#dataprocclustercreateoperator)):

```py
cluster_data['config']['lifecycleConfig']['idleDeleteTtl'] = '1800s'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach.

Try to delete the cluster from the program you run. When you finish your calculation, let your program call delete cluster command itself.

```
    print("Try to delete cluster %s " % job_args['cluster_name'] )
    result = subprocess.call(['gcloud',
                              'dataproc',
                              'clusters',
                              'delete',
                              job_args['cluster_name'],
                              '--quiet',
                              '--async'])
    print("Sent command result: %s" % str(result))
```